# Batch INSERT INTO mySQL or none insert none if any errors VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, batch-processing, insert-into

I downloaded the transaction records (ticker, time, volume, the closing price) of a ticker from a webpage. Since each page only display 20 transactions, and I determine the total no of pages and then do the looping to get all the records.

As I could not find an unique ID for that from the webpage and also even same ticker same time, same volume and same price could happened.
Originally I update to mySQL database one record by one record, however, problems may come. If there is an error in between, say the 30th one out of 150 records. It's troublesome to delete the previous record and redo again or whatever. What I want is to **either ALL** 150 records could be successfully inserted into the table **or NONE** if there is any error which would prompt me for fix it. Please help.

If so, I would store all the values got from all records in all Pages into an array, say arrValue(iNoOfRecords, Value) <- Another problem may arise, if so, I'm afraid the data type would be lost in my array. and then insert into the database, mySQL. Repeat the below for say 150 times due to have 150 records.

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ticker", Ticker)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", Price)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Volume", Volume)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyTime", MyTime)
```

the above x 150 set

Or Can I do the "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()" at the end of all records in all pages finished adding all parameters. i.e. The following code will be run after all parameters has been inserted.

```
 Try
      cnn.Open()
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
 Catch ex As Exception
      MsgBox(ex.ToString)
 End Try
```

Data type of the fields in mySql, Engine: InnoDB, table: Blocktrade
{Ticker, string}, {Price, decimal(10,3)} ,{Volume,BIGINT} 
(I don't know how to specify it in the array in vb.net)

Here's below part of the VB.Net currently using:

```
 Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Blocktrade (Ticker,Price, Volume, MyTime) VALUES (@Ticker,@Price,@MyTime)", cnn)
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ticker", Ticker)
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", Price)
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Volume", Volume)
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyTime", MyTime)
         Try
              cnn.Open()
              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
         Catch ex As Exception
              MsgBox(ex.ToString)
         End Try
    End Using
```

This is just my 'silly' thought', I don't know if VB.Net and mySQL could achieve so. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`SqlTransaction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to be able to rollback changes if problem occur before all insert operations completed, for example (adapted from [MSDN: `BeginTransaction()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86773566%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)) :

```
Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    connection.Open()

    Dim command As SqlCommand = connection.CreateCommand()
    Dim transaction As SqlTransaction

    ' Start a insert transaction'
    transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("InsertTransaction")

    ' Must assign both transaction object and connection' 
    ' to Command object for a pending insert transaction.'
    command.Connection = connection
    command.Transaction = transaction

    Try
        'Prepare command and do all Insert operations here'

        ' Attempt to commit the transaction.'
        transaction.Commit()
        Console.WriteLine("Also records are inserted to database.")

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Commit Exception Type: {0}", ex.GetType())
        Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex.Message)

        ' Attempt to roll back the transaction. '
        Try
            transaction.Rollback()

        Catch ex2 As Exception
            ' This catch block will handle any errors that may have occurred '
            ' on the server that would cause the rollback to fail, such as '
            ' a closed connection.'
            Console.WriteLine("Rollback Exception Type: {0}", ex2.GetType())
            Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex2.Message)
        End Try 
    End Try 
End Using
```